# How to pause splash screen for 3 secs in react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have implemented a splash screen by using react native navigation but unable to add a delay for 3 sec in the splash screen.

Comment: Did you try setTimeout() function?

Comment: @MdIsfarUddinAlNur
In react-native-navigation, for the splash screen, all the configurations are done in the android folder and its file so we can't use setTimeout() function over there as it is a javascript function.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try this in the splash screen activity? 
handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // change activity
        // finish current activity
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

Comment: ok i will try this @MdIsfarUddinAlNur